# Flow is Error is occurring

Tags: apex, community, email, flow

[image]New Cases is created by internal user.

The flow should look at the associated Account and the Contacts related to that account.

The Account, Related Contact emails should receive an email alerting the Community User that there is a new case assigned but it is emailing all the user inside the Org.

And thus resulting in email error(as maximum defined 5 for a flow)

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your flow and maybe the process that kicks it off?

Comment: @cricketlang I have attached the screenshot , It needs to be sent when a new case is created , the account owner with the case , and the contacts needs to receive the mail but mail is sending to all user

Comment: Do you have a Process kicking this off that passes the new Case Id to this flow?

Comment: @cricketlang yep there is a process builder that is associated when it is created , in the error I am seeing the account id in the flow is setting as null